# How to iterate through database objects in C# using SMO

Tags: c#, smo

I am trying to backup my database objects' scripts to disk. I have been able to put together the below code that does this, but I have to specify each object type (eg Tables, Functions, Stored Procedures).

Is there a way to loop through all these objects without specifying each collection?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public static void BackupDB(Server srv, Database db, string savePath)
{
    string objPath;
    string objFile;
    string objTxt;

    foreach (StoredProcedure obj in db.StoredProcedures) 
    {
        if (obj.IsSystemObject == false)
        {
            objPath = savePath + "Stored Procedures\\";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(objPath);

            objFile = objPath + obj.Schema + "." + obj.Name + ".sql";
            objTxt = GetScriptString(srv, obj);
            File.WriteAllText(objFile, objTxt);
        }
    }

    foreach (Table obj in db.Tables)
    {
        if (obj.IsSystemObject == false)
        {
            objPath = savePath + "Tables\\";
            Directory.CreateDirectory(objPath);

            objFile = objPath + obj.Schema + "." + obj.Name + ".txt";
            objTxt = GetScriptString(srv, obj);
            File.WriteAllText(objFile, objTxt);
        }
    }

static private string GetScriptString(Server server, SqlSmoObject obj)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    Scripter scr = new Scripter(server);
    var script = scr.EnumScript(new SqlSmoObject[] { obj });
    foreach (var line in script)
    {
        output.AppendLine(line);
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

EDIT:
Using Grant Winney's answer, I was able to put together the below method to get iterate through all the objects without repeating lines:

```
public static void BackupDB(Server srv, Database db, string savePath)
{
    string objPath;
    string objFile;
    string objTxt;

    Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ScriptSchemaObjectBase>> dboDict =
        new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ScriptSchemaObjectBase>>();

    dboDict.Add("Stored Procedures", db.StoredProcedures.Cast<StoredProcedure>().Where(x => !x.IsSystemObject));
    dboDict.Add("Functions", db.UserDefinedFunctions.Cast<UserDefinedFunction>().Where(x => !x.IsSystemObject));
    dboDict.Add("Tables", db.Tables.Cast<Table>().Where(x => !x.IsSystemObject));
    dboDict.Add("Views", db.Views.Cast<View>().Where(x => !x.IsSystemObject));

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<ScriptSchemaObjectBase>> dict in dboDict)
    {
        IEnumerable<ScriptSchemaObjectBase> dboObjects = dict.Value;
        objPath = savePath + dict.Key + "\\";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(objPath);

        foreach (ScriptSchemaObjectBase obj in dboObjects)
        {
            objFile = objPath + obj.Schema + "." + obj.Name + ".sql";
            objTxt = GetScriptString(srv, obj);
            File.WriteAllText(objFile, objTxt);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the similar code into a separate method, and take advantage of the fact that each of those classes implements the same base class, which is where `Schema` and `Name` are located.

You can use LINQ to filter the items first, then pass the filtered list to the other method.

```
public static void BackupDB(Server srv, Database db, string savePath)
{
    string objPath;
    string objFile;
    string objTxt;

    BackupObjects(db.StoredProcedures.Cast<StoredProcedure>().Where(x => !x.IsSystemObject));
    BackupObjects(db.Tables.Cast<Table>().Where(x => !x.IsSystemObject));
}

private static void BackupObjects(IEnumerable<ScriptSchemaObjectBase> objects)
{
    foreach (ScriptSchemaObjectBase obj in objects)
    {
        objPath = savePath + "Stored Procedures\\";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(objPath);

        objFile = objPath + obj.Schema + "." + obj.Name + ".sql";
        objTxt = GetScriptString(srv, obj);
        File.WriteAllText(objFile, objTxt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm a noob on Enums and LINQ, but using this I was able to get something to work (see my edit). It still feels like I'm repeating lines by added each DB object separately, but again, I'm not 100% on how enums like this work.